# Web application design ideas

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, web-applications, wcf-client

Here is the situation I need to deal with. I appreciate any kind of input.
There is a tennis court all wired with sensors. The net, the lines all have built-in sensors. All these sensors are sending signals to a USB device which is connected to a laptop computer(COMP1). There are also 2 projector screens in the court for the spectators. Projectors are connected to a separate computer(COMP2) and they can act as external monitors. I want to develop an event-driven application and run it on COMP1 which will be monitoring the sensors. When it gets a signal, it would send a message to COMP2 which then displays the info on the projectors in a web browser. Both computers are wifi enabled. How would you design such a system? Would you use ajax , web services, wcf, javascript? Obviously, it will have a server (COMP1) and a client (COMP2). I don't want to run a timer on COMP2 to poll the sensors. I want it pure event-driven. Sensor -> COMP1 -> COMP2 -> screen

Thanks for your help, in advance.

Comment: Why are you using web technologies? Seems to be the wrong choice.

Comment: What would you recommend? Socket programming? two desktop applications communicating using TCP or UDP protocols?

Answer (score 0):

I propably would have a look at Python Twisted for COMP1 for reading the sensor values in Python and serving as websocket server. COMP2 could be a simple device with a decent webbrowser with websocket support and some javascript to process the data. Pretty simple solution and since you only have to support 1 computer/browser you don't need to deal with a fallback for non websocket browsers.